# How to reuse Promise<void> after using it once in my Angular service?

Tags: promise, signalr, angular10

I have a problem with my Angular `Promise<void>` in one of my services.

The service establishes SignalR connection with the server's hub. And I am waiting with broadcasting to the hub for connection to be established:

```
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  private url = environment.apiUrl + 'messageHub';
  private thenable: Promise<void>;

public startConnection = (): void => {
    if (!this.hubConnection) {
      const token = this.auth.getAuth().token;
      this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(this.url, { accessTokenFactory: () => token })
        .build();
      this.startHubConnection();

      this.hubConnection.onclose(() => this.connectionHubClosed());
    }
  };

private startHubConnection() {
    this.thenable = this.hubConnection.start();
    this.thenable
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
      .catch((err) => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));
  }

public broadcastGameState = (): void => {
    this.thenable.then(() => {
      const name = this.auth.getAuth().displayName;
      let message = this.game.getGame();
      this.hubConnection
        .invoke('SendMessage', message)
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    });
  };
```

But after I will close my connection with:

```
public stopConnection = (): void => {
    if (this.hubConnection) {
      this.hubConnection.stop();
    }
  };
```

and use again my service, I can not use my `thenable` anymore, and `broadcastGameState` does not wait anymore for it, throwing an error:

> Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected'
> State.

I do not understand why?

Comment: "and `broadcastGameState" does not wait anymore for it, throwing an error"
Well, at that point, it's already a resolved promise, it should just run right away.

Comment: @xxh you got your point and made me thinking, so I found the problem :) Described in the Answer.

Comment: Great to hear, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xxh** you got your point and made me thinking, so I found the problem :) After calling:

```
public stopConnection = (): void => {
    if (this.hubConnection) {
      this.hubConnection.stop();
    }
  };
```

on connection close is called:

```
private connectionHubClosed(): void {
    //trigerred when lost connection with server
    alert('todo: SignalR connection closed');
  }
```

BUT  this.hubConnection is still with assigned value, so because of `if (!this.hubConnection)` new `this.thenable` was skipped.